AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained took forever to load
I used the following code to load my custom-trained tokenizer:
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
test_tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('raptorkwok/cantonese-tokenizer-test')

It took forever to load. Even if I replace the AutoTokenizer with PreTrainedTokenizerFast, it still loads forever.
How to debug or fix this issue?

Where can we find the pretrained model?

It is just a SentencePieceBPETokenizer trained by datasets. The files are at: https://huggingface.co/raptorkwok/cantonese-tokenizer-test

Looks like there is something wrong with that tokenizer. It seems that you created it. If so, could you load it locally before uploading it to the hub? If you could, maybe the problem is related with the push_to_hub call.

The problem is resolved when downgrading transformers version to 4.28.1 from 4.41.0. Both pipeline() and from_pretrained() load the tokenizer successfully in seconds.

The problem is resolved when using transformers version of 4.41.0.
!pip install transformers==4.41.0

from transformers import AutoTokenizer
test_tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('raptorkwok/cantonese-tokenizer-test')


I was using 4.41.0 (the latest version at this moment), the problem still exists. But when I downgrade to 4.28.0, the problem is gone.

I load custom autotokenizer:
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
path_autotokenizer = ...
new_tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(path_autotokenizer)

and it doesn't work with transformers==4.41.2 - can't load at all. With dependencies below, it does work:
tokenizer == 0.13.3
transformers == 4.31.0


Yes, the key version is tokenizer 0.13.3 , transformers 4.28.1 to 4.31.0 can work too

Actually it's just a workaround, not the best solution. Because sometimes you explicitly need latest transformer versions. E.g. it seems like flash_attention_2 is not accessible from older versions...
Another workaround would be to construct new tokenizer on flight inside script.
